# python gnupg.encrypt : no errors but not encrypting data or files

Tags: python, encryption, gnupg

using python-gnupg v0.3.5 on windows 7 w/Python 2.7 and GPG4Win v2.2.0

test_gnupg.py results in 2 failures:

> > Test that searching for keys works ... FAIL
> >
> > Doctest: gnupg.GPG.recv_keys ... FAIL

2 keyrings exist in each of these locations(secring & pubring in each):

> > under the GPGHome directory (C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU\GnuPG)
> >
> > under the user profile(C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\gnupg)

If I create GPG instance and set the keyring file path to the user profile pubring.pgp I get a result from GPG.list_keys(). If I let it use the gpghome directory pubring.pgp I get no results from list_keys() because that keyring is empty.

So given I specify the user profile keyring and I have a key to use this is what happens:

```
    >>>data = '1234 abcd 56678'
    >>>fingerprint = u'<fingerprint>'
    >>>enc = gpg.encrypt(data,fingerprint)
    >>>enc.data
    ''
```

encrypt_file() gives the same results, nothing happens, no errors. I'm not particularly savvy in any of this but it seems like if I have data and public key this should be dead simple. I'm having a horrendous time trying to determine what is wrong given I see no log files anywhere and I have no errors when attempting this.

How can I determine what is going wrong here? 
I've read pretty much everything I can find here on StackOverflow, http://pythonhosted.org/python-gnupg/#getting-started and the google group for python-gnupg.

Also why do I have 2 separate sets of keyrings in the first place?

edit: 
clarified there are 2 separate sets of pubring and secring

edit 2:
answer below was instrumental in leading to the actual problem.
the gnupg.GPG() constructor is setting gpg command line options that include 'no-tty', calling gnupg.GPG(options='') resolves the issue and successfully encrypts both data and files.

Comment: By default you have a pubring.gpg and secring.gpg file in the home directory.  The former stores public keys and the latter stores private keys.  As for the rest of your question ... I normally just call GPG on the command line so I'll have to dig into this module later and come back to it (unless someone beats me to it).  Also there has already been wine poured on this side of the planet, so it might take a while.

Comment: Indeed, I'm familiar with pubring and secring, but I have 2 of each, one under the user profile and one in the GPG home.
Amending question to specify that info.

Comment: One set will be the keyrings for your user account on the system and the other set will be global defaults for the system.  Probably.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I finally got around to looking at this and got basic encryption to work from the command line.  Here's an example that will work to encrypt data entered from the command line:

```
import gnupg

gpg_home = "/path/to/gnupg/home"
gpg = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome=gpg_home)

data = raw_input("Enter data to encrypt: ")
rkey = raw_input("Enter recipient's key ID: ")

encrypted_ascii_data = gpg.encrypt(data, rkey)

print(encrypted_ascii_data)
```

Change the gpg_home to whichever of those two GnuPG paths you want to use.  The first one looks like the default installation location and the second one appears to be specific to your user account.  The script will prompt for some text to encrypt and a key ID to encrypt to, then print the ASCII armoured encrypted data to stdout.

EDIT: I'm not certain, but I suspect the reason your code failed was either due to using the whole fingerprint for the recipient key ID, which is unnecessary (I used the 0xLONG format, an example of which is on my profile), or you called the wrong GPG home directory.

EDIT 2: This works to encrypt files and writes the output to a file in the same directory, it will work as is on *nix systems.  You will need to change the gpg_home as with the above example:

```
import gnupg

gpg_home = "~/.gnupg"
gpg = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome=gpg_home)

data = raw_input("Enter full path of file to encrypt: ")
rkeys = raw_input("Enter key IDs separated by spaces: ")
savefile = data+".asc"

afile = open(data, "rb")
encrypted_ascii_data = gpg.encrypt_file(afile, rkeys.split(), always_trust=True, output=savefile)
afile.close()
```

My work here is done!  :)

BTW, both these examples use Python 2.7, for Python 3 you'll need to modify the raw_input() lines to use input() instead.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this Ben.

Unfortunately I can't reproduce working results. The outcome is the same; no data is encapsulated in the gnupg.Crypt object after calling encrypt(). I've tried using the full fingerprint, the key id, and the value in the "subkey" field.

I'm going to work on implementing some logging to get more info. I had been trying to work this from the command line to prototype some new code but it's looking pretty grim.

Comment: Something more basic is wrong.  DEBUG:gnupg:gpg: Sorry, no terminal at all requested - can't get input  DEBUG:gnupg:encrypt result: ''

Comment: That's a GPG error message, not from python-gnupg.  Check your gpg.conf for the line "no-tty" and if it's there, remove it.

Comment: No line for 'no-tty' exists in gpg.conf.
I'm strongly considering scrapping this idea and seeing what I can do with C#.

Comment: I've been able to isolate the issue.

the constructor is setting default options that include the 'no-tty' flag, using GPG(options='') disables that flag and appears to resolve the issue.

Thanks very much Ben, your help was invaluable in tracking this down.

Comment: Excellent!  I guess now my work really is done ... ;)