# script that asks for password to gpg-sign with default key

Tags: python, gnupg

i'm trying to gpg-sign a file using `python-gnupgp`.

This should be rather simple:

my code is simple:

```
import gnupg
import sys

gpg = gnupg.GPG()
stream = open(sys.argv[1], "rb")
signed_data = gpg.sign_file(stream)

print("signed data: %s" % (signed_data.data))
print("stderr: %s" % (signed_data.stderr))
```

now the above code does not work, as I don't provide a passphrase to `gpg.sign_file()`, and gnupg cannot ask for it, as the error indicates:

> signed data: b''
>
> stderr: [GNUPG:] USERID_HINT 1234567890ABCDEF me myself <me@example.com>
>
> [GNUPG:] NEED_PASSPHRASE 1234567890ABCDEF 1234567890ABCDEF 1 0
>
> gpg: Sorry, no terminal at all requested - can't get input

according to [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19298171) the problem is likely a default of having `no-tty` in the default GPG-options.

now i think that the `no-tty` option makes sense, and i would like to provide a way to ask for the passphrase and then supply it to the `sign_file` call.

in the simplest case, something like:

```
import getpass
pw=getpass.getpass()
signed_data=gpg.sign_file(stream, passphrase=pw)
```

no my problem is, that i would like to tell the user, which key's passphrase they are being asked for.
something like

```
print("Please enter the passphrase for key %s" % defaultkey_id)
pw=getpass.getpass()
```

which turns out suprisingly hard to do, as i haven't found a way to query the ID of the default key. a simple `gpg.list_keys(True)[0]` gives a random private key (well not random; most likely the first one added to the keyring; but that need not be the default key).

So i guess my real question is: how can i find out what is the default key used for signing, so i can ask the user for a passphrase for this very key?

(i'd rather not parse the content of `$GNUPGHOME/gpg.conf`)

Answer (score 1):

If you have gpgconf available, you could parse the output of `gpgconf gpg`, which should list (among the other configured options) the configured default-key.