# gnupg.GPG: Sorry, no terminal at all requested - can't get input

Tags: python, gnupg

I am trying to encrypt a file using Python GNUPG library and it doesnt work!

Here is my code snippet:

```
import gnupg

gpg=gnupg.GPG(homedir='/home/datadev/')
recipients=['realname@email.com']
f = open('/home/datadev/filename','rb')
status = gpg.encrypt(f,recipients)
```

`/home/datadev` is the folder where I have my `.asc` file and all `.pubring` files related to `gpg`.

After reading the post [***gpg: Sorry, no terminal at all requested - can't get input***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19298171/python-gnupg-encrypt-no-errors-but-not-encrypting-data-or-files)

I tried out the following option:

```
gpg=gnupg.GPG(options='')
```

but the error is always "gpg: Sorry, no terminal at all requested - can't get input"

It would be helpful if someone could advise me as to what is wrong.

Comment: **How** is it not working?

Answer (score 0):

The message about the terminal indicates that there is something wrong, but gnupg cannot tell it as there is no terminal. The python wrapper calls the gnupg executable. Apparently, the gnupg output is not consistent in a way that everything comes back with a return code etc. 
So the problem is a different one. I faced the same issue. After passing in the recipients not as a list but just straight it worked. The code documentation of encrypt gives an example for multiple recipients - just pass them as single parameters. Converting list to string would to the trick in the above example.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is the PGP/GPG feature needs to be activated in WHM.  I had this feature working, then after altering the features for an account's Package as defined in WHM, it stopped working.  I went back and noticed this option had been unchecked.  Checked it, ran my code again and, success.